# Selenium-Unable to identify the search box element using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

```java
    WebElement SearchField = 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input"));
    SearchField.sendKeys("my name");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    
    WebElement SearchButton = 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]"));
    SearchButton.submit(); 
    Thread.sleep(3000);
             
    driver.quit();
```

In above code I have tried to select the search box in google.com and enter "my name" as the value.
but it says xpath element not found.
So I took the "name" instead of xpath element and it worked.

```java
WebElement SearchField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
```

How can I run this using xpath?

Comment: My xpath is a bit rusty but I think if you are giving an absolute path from the root of the document you need to start it with // not /

Comment: You should have clarified the exact link you are testing and if you are logged in or not.

Comment: @Rob no, the `/` is correct for the absolute xpath. however I'd recommend basically **never** to use the absolute xpath in your tests, instead use a selector like @Prophet has provided.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to switch to xpath if name works fine ?

There are lot of advantage if you use `ID, NAME, LINKTEXT, PARTIALLINKTEXT, CSSSELECTOR, CLASSNAME` and lastly `XPATH` :

Anyway you can try this **xpath** :

```
//input[@name='q']
```

this is a relative xpath. The one you are using is absolute xpath. try to avoid that.

Comment: Thank you it worked. I thought its just  coping the relative xpath from the inspect.

Comment: @manulwickramanayaka  : If you copy then it would always be absolute xpath. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @cruisepandey `//input[@name='q']` is not an unique selector there....

Comment: @Prophet : it is a unique element. Check it out [here](https://ibb.co/34FJJ2y)

Comment: it has to be unique if `name='q'` works then xpath will definitely works

Comment: No :) You tested on a wrong page. Open https://www.google.com/. You will see 2 elements located by `//input[@name='q']` however the desired element is the first one.

Comment: @Prophet : Man I am going mad about this. But Check it by your own [here](https://ibb.co/xzLWKkg), you can see google URL and developer tool 1/1 entry ?

Comment: @Prophet: Just curious. Can you share the screenshot of where you see 2 elements located by ```lang-html //input[@name='q']``` in the page

Comment: Guys, you both are right. Selector is unique if a user is not logged in and not unique for logged in user.

Comment: @vitaliis : `not unique for logged in user` I am logged in and it is unique.

Comment: he is not at parent URL which is `google.com` he is at `google.com\seacrch?q....` and that is the issue

Comment: Well, I am logged in and the locator is not unique.

Comment: @vitaliis : that sounds like a accepting comment.

Comment: The locator becomes not unique after a search is done. The second element is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The unique XPath for the search input element you are looking is:

```
//input[@name='q' and @type='text']
```